# readiness and liveness issue with springboot 2.2 and kubernetes version 1.13 in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator, amazon-eks

What I have

1. Springboot 2.2.1
2. kubernetes 1.13 using EKS
3. openjdk 11
4. cloud: AWS

application.yaml in my springboot application

```
server:
  port: 8443
  servlet:
    context-path: /api
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
      group:
        readiness:
          include: '*'
          show-details: always
        liveness:
          include: '*'
          show-details: always
```

On my local when I start springboot application: I can see health as follows - 
https://localhost:8443/api/actuator/health

When I try to access https://localhost:8443/api/actuator/health/readiness or https://localhost:8443/api/actuator/health/liveness  I get error

> This localhost page can’t be found. No webpage was found for the web
>   address: http://localhost:8443/api/actuator/health/readiness HTTP
>   ERROR 404

**Question 1 - Is this an expected behaviour? readiness or liveness probe can not be tested with just springboot without deploying it to kubernetes? **

deployment.yaml in kubernetes

```
  readinessProbe:
    httpGet:
      port: 8443
      path: api/actuator/health
      scheme: HTTPS
    initialDelaySeconds: 60
    failureThreshold: 2
    periodSeconds: 60
    timeoutSeconds: 5
  livenessProbe:
    httpGet:
      port: 8443
      path: api/actuator/health
      scheme: HTTPS
    initialDelaySeconds: 120
    failureThreshold: 2
    periodSeconds: 60
    timeoutSeconds: 5
```

My application takes around 30-50 seconds to start, thats why I have kept initialdelayseconds or periodseconds as 60

ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: 'my-ingress'
  namespace: 'my-namespace'
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig":
      { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxx
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: "EKS-ALB-sg"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: 200-499
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: <ingress-tag>
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: <ingress alb>
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
spec:
  rules:
    - host: <host-name>
      http:
        paths:
         - path: /*
           backend:
             serviceName: 'my-service'
             servicePort: 8443
```

for this configuration when I try to deploy to kubernetes on EKS cluster, I get error like below:

I see error like below when I describe pod.

```
  Warning  Unhealthy  48s                  kubelet, <ip>.ec2.internal  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
  Warning  Unhealthy  44s                  kubelet, <ip>.ec2.internal  Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503


Warning  Unhealthy  105s (x2 over 2m45s)  kubelet, <ip>.ec2.internal  Readiness probe failed: Get https://<ip>:8443/api/actuator/health: dial tcp <>:8443: connect: connection refused
      Warning  Unhealthy  46s                   kubelet, <ip>.ec2.internal  Liveness probe failed: Get https://<ip>:8443/api/actuator/health: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
      Warning  Unhealthy  40s                   kubelet, <ip>.ec2.internal  Readiness probe failed: Get https://<ip>:8443/api/actuator/health: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

**Question 2:
Is it due to ingress taking time to create host?
Or Is there anything else I might be doing wrong?**

Comment: You use port 8443 that indicates HTTPS but in the error message for local access to the probe URLs it says http. Is this just a typo or maybe the source of the issue?

Comment: @christian-frommeyer as stated on local I tried was with just springboot app. I didn’t even check this with kubernetes on my local.  Theats why there is question1. 
Looks like you missed that part. Now about question2 About 8443 I have added *scheme: HTTPS* in deployment.yaml that’s when I tried to deploy springboot app to EKS. 
I hope questions were clear :)

Comment: This works for me (using spring boot 2.3.0 atm). You where just mixing up https and http right above your **question1** So I was unsure if with your complete setup that might be the issue.